# TFS User Profiles Not Updating

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, active-directory

We are using TFS V.15.  It's my understanding TFS sits on top of SharePoint and SharePoint gets user updates from Active Directory.  I was under the impression TFS users get updated from TFSJobAgent.exe.  TFSJobAgent.exe is running successfully but there are a couple of names in TFS that are not changing.  For example we have one user where their name in TFS has a period at the end of it.  We checked AD and sure enough there was a period in AD.  We removed the period from AD but it persists in TFS.  How can I fix it so the users get updated properly?

Answer (score 1):

This should be an **Identity Synchronization** issue. Changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS immediately. Instead, TFS will synchronize those groups regularly.

You could either force synchronization for fasting the retrieving the result or wait the synchronization to happen after sometimes. Check this [blog](http://mohamedradwan.com/2013/12/29/force-synchronizing-tfs-2013-users-with-windows-accounts/) which discusses how to do a force sync. Basically, run the job using the Web Service “**JobWebService**”.

More related thread talking about Identity Synchronization for your reference:

- [Identity Synchronization in Team Foundation Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vasu_sankaran/2010/06/07/identity-synchronization-in-team-foundation-server-2010/)
- [Force TFS to sync with Active Directory](https://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2011/02/17/force-tfs-to-sync-with-active-directory/)

Comment: It seems mine are not getting updated at all.  The names were cganged in AS a couple days ago.  In fact, I cganged the display names directly in the TFS SQL table and the reverted to the wrong name.  Is there a possible caching issue I can check for and if so how?

Comment: Also... I do not see the JobWebService.  I only see WarehouseControlService.

Comment: @BillGreer Did you directly modify  the original  SQL database data, actually it's highly not recommend to do this in TFS. The blog is for TFS2013 maybe not all suitable for TFS15,  However, you could also try this workaround,  remove tfs_users group and add it back and then TFS it will syncs with AD.

Comment: @BillGreer  Any update  on this issue? Have you figure it out? Did my reply helped  or gave a right direction?

Comment: I have not tried removing the tfs_users group yet.  I will do so.  It's very strange that it's only happening in one collection within TFS.Should I remove the users group from just the collection where I am seeing a display name issue?

Comment: @BillGreer This may due to you have changed the SQL table for that collection database. Did you changed all collection database or just for that specific one? Yes, you could remove the users group from that collection and add back again, which may do the trick. If the issue still exists, you may have to restore your collection database backup,then update the user info again.

Comment: So each collection has it's own database where user display names can be overridden?  What would such a table be called?

Comment: @BillGreer  There is a displaypart column, you could take a look at this question:https://superuser.com/questions/447521/tfs-2010-cannot-query-certain-users , Not recommend to directly edit the database. Suggest you to restore the database, due to you may broken something in the collection database caused the issue.

Comment: Sure enough the user DisplayPart value in the collection in question has the incorrect value.  I know it's not recommended to change values directly in the table, but in this case I don't have an option to restore the database.  I don't see the harm in changing this value.  The SID for the user is correct in this table.  Could me changing the DisplayPart actually break something in TFS?

Comment: @BillGreer Touch TFS database directly may not  break something, however  it will void the support agreement or it is not supported. If you insist on doing this, suggest you first back-up your collection database, then change that value to see if the issue solved.